# Java Spring - return from asynchronous callback?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-authentication

Working on a backend with Spring (Java) and Firebase.  We are using the Firebase tokens (appended as an authentication header) to identify the user, using the [built in UID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

Unfortunately, extracting this UID from the token must be done asynchronously, so I can only get the token from the `onSuccess` callback.
To serve a response, I must return an object from the below `deleteUser` method, however *I cannot know what the response will be until I get a success/failure callback!*

I can imagine a way to do this by waiting on a flag which is set my the callback, or with some messy timing, but I'm wondering if there is a clean way of handling this without introducing race conditions or lots of extra code.  Can anyone help?

#### Request Mapping (handles request, serves response)

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public @ResponseBody String deleteUser(@RequestHeader("Authentication") String token) {
        FirebaseUtil.getUid(token, new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken decodedToken) {
                String uid = decodedToken.getUid();
                //RETURN SUCCESSFUL HERE
            }
        }, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                //RETURN FAILURE HERE
            }
        });

        //MUST RETURN SOMETHING HERE?
        User userToDelete = userDao.get(uid); //DONT HAVE THE uid HERE
        userDao.delete(uid);
        clearUserAccounts(userToDelete);
        return uid + " was deleted";
    }
```

#### FirebaseUtil.getUid()

```
public static void getUid(String token, OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken> successListener, OnFailureListener failureListener) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                .verifyIdToken(token)
                .addOnSuccessListener(successListener)
                .addOnFailureListener(failureListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there are ways to block the thread until the asynchronous request finishes, there is a simple and more resource-effective solution since Spring 3.2.

You can use `DeferredResult<T>` as your return type to enable asynchronous processing. This allows the servlet container to reuse the HTTP worker thread right away, while sparing you the headache of forcefully serializing a chain of asynchronous requests.

By filling out the comments, your code would look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public DeferredResult<String> deleteUser(@RequestHeader("Authentication") String token) {
    final DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();

    FirebaseUtil.getUid(token, new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken decodedToken) {
            String uid = decodedToken.getUid();
            User userToDelete = userDao.get(uid);
            userDao.delete(uid);
            clearUserAccounts(userToDelete);
            result.setResult(uid + " was deleted");
        }
    }, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            result.setErrorResult(e);
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I also recently discovered Callables, which seem to work in a similar manner with the exception of having to override `call()`?  Would they work, and if not, why? http://xpadro.blogspot.ca/2015/07/understanding-callable-and-spring.html

Comment: Nice find. Callables are similar, as noted by the blog post, but there they are not applicable to your problem. Callable must wrap a (potentially long running) _synchronous_ request, while the Firebase method is purely asynchronous.